# Implementing generic type interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

Let's say I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface MvpView { }

public interface MvpPresenter<V extends MvpView> {
    void attach(V view);
}
```

Then a base class that implements `MvpPresenter`

```
public class BasePresenter<V extends MvpView> implements MvpPresenter<V> {
    private V view;

    @Override
    public void attach(V view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

And finally the following class that extends BasePresenter

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<P extends MvpPresenter> implements MvpView {
    P presenter;

    public void someMethod() {
        presenter.attach(this);
    }
}
```

While this compiles it's not safe because there is no guarantee that implementations of the class will implement the correct `MvpView` (the one that `P presenter` uses). In order to be safe I've left out the code of `someMethod` and every implementation must fill it with the exact same code `presenter.attach(this)`

What I'd like to do but I don't know how is something like the following:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<V extends MvpView, P extends MvpPresenter<V>> implements V {
    P presenter;

    public void someMethod() {
        presenter.attach(this);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on boobalan gnanasekaran and user158037 answers, I did it like this:

```
public interface MvpView { }

public interface MvpPresenter<V extends MvpView> {
    void attach(V view);
}

public class BasePresenter<V extends MvpView> implements MvpPresenter<V> {
    private V view;

    @Override
    public void attach(V view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public V getView() {
        return view;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseFragment<V extends MvpView, P extends MvpPresenter<V>> {
    P presenter;

    protected abstract V getThis();

    public void someMethod() {
        presenter.attach(getThis());
    }

    public P getPresenter() { return presenter; }
}
```

And an example implementation

```
public interface MoviesContract {
    interface Presenter extends MvpPresenter<MoviesContract.View> {
        void loadMovies();
    }

    interface View extends MvpView {
        void onMoviesLoaded();
    }
}

public class MoviesPresenter extends BasePresenter<MoviesContract.View>
    implements MoviesContract.Presenter {

    @Override
    public void loadMovies() {
        getView.onMoviesLoaded();
    }
}


public class MoviesFragment extends BaseFragment<MoviesContract.View, MoviesContract.Presenter>
    implements MoviesContract.View {

    @Override
    public MoviesContract.View getThis() {
        return this;
    }

    public loadMovies() {
        getPresenter().loadMovies();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMoviesLoaded() {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Declare `BaseFragment` like this.

```
abstract class BaseFragment<P extends MvpPresenter<R>, R extends BaseFragment<P,R>> implements MvpView {
    P presenter;

   public void someMethod() {
        presenter.attach(getThis());
   }

   abstract R getThis();
   }
}
```

and use the extensions like this,

```
class MyFragment extends BaseFragment<MvpPresenter<MyFragment>, MyFragment> {

    @Override
    MyFragment getThis() {
        return this;
    }   

}
```

Comment: Works, but now instead of having interfaces deriving from MvpView I need to have many BaseFragment abstract classes with abstract methods and I don't want that.

Comment: Just this one Abstract class will do. You can always extend many classes right? like  `class MyAnotherFragment extends BaseFragment<MvpPresenter<MyAnotherFragment>, MyAnotherFragment>`

Comment: But I don't want abstract classes, but interfaces. You gave me an idea though. I'll post my solution soon.

Comment: I just used the same abstract class you posted; just modified it. Any if you the idea, cheers

Answer (score 1):

This compiles:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<P extends MvpPresenter<BaseFragment>> implements MvpView {

    P presenter;

    public void someMethod() {
        presenter.attach(this);
    }
}
```

But I haven't found a way to actually subclass it. I am not sure if MvpView is actually required for anything. Maybe something like this will be useful:

```
public interface MvpPresenter<V> {

    void attach(V view);
}

public class BasePresenter<V> implements MvpPresenter<V> {
    private V view;

    @Override
    public void attach(V view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseFragment<R extends BaseFragment>  {

    MvpPresenter<R> presenter;

    public void someMethod() {
        presenter.attach(getThis());
    }

    abstract R getThis();
}

public class MyBaseFragment extends BaseFragment<MyBaseFragment> {

    @Override
    MyBaseFragment getThis() {
        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Imagine that inside MyBaseFragment I need to say presenter.getView().doSomething(), so I need interfaces deriving from MvpView for each BaseFragment implementation, so they will know what their views can do. With your way i'd need to have many BaseFragment classes instead of many interfaces.